# Why is my script calling multiple functions?

Tags: bash, test

I have a few sets of scripts that I've written to make setting up linux very simple. So I have made those scripts into separate functions instead and put it all in one script. I have numbers set so when the user inputs one of the numbers, it will call that function. However, when the user inputs one number, the script calls ALL the functions:

```
n=1
#note you need spaces between [ ]
while [ $n == 1 ]
do
    echo "Base install=1"
    echo "Mintrepos=2"
    echo "Asusn13 driver=3"
    echo "Install Standard openbox=4"
    echo "Install Xfceopenbox=5"
    echo "backing up standard open box config=6"
    echo "backing up openboxfce=7"
    echo
    read choice
    if [ "$choice"==1 ]
    then
        baseinstall
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==2 ]
    then
        linuxmintrepos
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==3 ]
    then
        asusn13driver
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==4 ]
    then
        standardopenbox
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==5 ]
    then
        xfceopenbox
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==6 ]
    then
        backupstandopenbox
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==7 ]
    then
        backupxfc4openbox
    fi
    echo "You installed: "
    if [ "$choice"==1 ]
    then
        echo "baseinstall"
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==2 ]
    then
        echo "linuxmintrepos"
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==3 ]
    then
        echo asusn13driver
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==4 ]
    then
        echo "standardopenbox"
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==5 ]
    then
        echo "xfceopenbox"
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==6 ]
    then
        echo "backupstandopenbox"
    fi
    if [ "$choice"==7 ]
    then
        echo "backupxfc4openbox"
        echo "If you would like to keep going, type in 1, if not, type in any other number"
    read n
    fi

done
```

Comment: This is not the problem about which you are asking, but it is still a problem. Go look up `case` statements.

Comment: @HalosGhost - `select` is a better fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need spaces around the `==`. Otherwise, you are passing the string `"$choice"==1`  itself to `if` rather than comparing `$choice` to `1`. When `[` receives a string, it will evaluate to true as long as the string is non-empty:

```
$ foo="bar";  [ $foo ] && echo true
true
$ foo="";  [ "$foo" ] && echo true  ## echoes nothing
```

Outside the `test` brackets, in the absence of space, the variable would actually get assigned to `=1`. To illustrate:

```
$ f==3
$ echo $f
=3
$ [ 10==12 ] && echo yes
yes
```

As you can see above, `f==3` sets the variable `$f` to `=3`.

So, in your `if` block, what is being tested is a non-empty string which always evaluates to true and the `if` is executed. This would work:

```
if [ "$choice" == "1" ]
then
    baseinstall
fi
```

Also, `=` or `==` do [string comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) in bash. You want arithmetic comparison:

```
if [ "$choice" -eq "1" ]
then
    baseinstall
fi
```

Comment: Very informative. I am learning a lot.

Comment: variables don't get assigned inside `[ ... ]`. What's happening is that the `[` command only receives one argument (other than `]`) -- the string "$choice==1". When `test` (or `[`) receives a single argument, the success condition is that the string is non-empty.

Comment: @glennjackman ouch. That should teach me not to post answers just before going to bed. Thanks, answer edited.

Comment: Couldn't I assign the number as a string and that would work? (not saying if this is more useful)

Comment: @munchschair in this example both work as long as you add a space around the `==`. The `-eq` is better because it is doing what you think its doing but in this case both the lexical and the arithmetic comparison should work.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
if [ "$choice"==1 ]
```

With:

```
if [ "$choice" = 1 ]
```

Do the same for all subsequent tests.

#### Explanation

When the shell sees `"$choice"==1`, it sees one string. If `choice` was, for example, 2, then it sees the string `2==1`.  This is not an equality test.  It is a string.  Since it is a non-empty string, the test returns true.  Hence all choices are executed.

In order to recognize the equality test, spaces are needed.

Separately, and as a minor point, for `[` style tests, the symbol for equality is `=`.  bash will accept `==` for that but it is not correct and won't work in other shells.

#### Exploring `[...]` tests on the command line

It is easy to explore how `[` tests work on the command line.  First, let's demonstrate that an empty string tests false:

```
$ if [ "" ]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
False
```

A non-empty string, whatever it is, is true:

```
$ if [ abc ]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
```

Now, let's look at `2==1`:

```
$ if [ 2==1 ]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
```

Since `2==1` is a non-empty string, it tests true.

Now, let's add spaces and do equality tests:

```
$ if [ 2 = 1 ]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
False
$ if [ 2 = 2 ]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
```

As an additional subtlety, `=` tests for string equality which happens to work fine here.  To test for numeric equality, use `-eq` instead.

```
$ if [ 2 -eq 2 ]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your `if test ...;fi` statements are syntactically incorrect, but also worth noting is your entire approach is a little rough. There are a couple of areas in which the flow of this script could be drastically improved - specifically in that it will be easier to read and edit later.

First, you can `set` your selections iteratively in a `for` loop. In this way any possible *choice* will be announced to the user and its selector automatically generated, but within the script you can lump them all together in a list of strings without worrying about either:

```
set --
for c in \
    "Base install:base_fn"                             \
    "Mintrepos:mint_fn"                                \
    "Asusn13 driver:asus_fn"                           \
    "Install Standard openbox:std_obox_fn"             \
    "Install Xfceopenbox:xfce_obox_fn"                 \
    "backing up standard open box config:bkup_fn obox" \
    "backing up openboxfce:bkup_fn xfce"              
do
    set -- "$@" "${c##*:}"
    printf "'%s' = $#\n" "${c%:*}"
done
```

This encodes the called `fn_name` into the positional parameter array while simultaneously printing the user friendly description to stdout.

Once you've built your list of selections into `"$@"` and printed the progress while doing so, you can then `read` the user's selection in a small loop that will quit after too many failed tries while also verifying its input:

```
chk=$((($#<1)*5))                           #if not at least one choice quit
until [ "$((chk+=1))" -gt 5 ] && exit 1     #chks up to 5 times or quits
printf '\nSelect: '                         #prompts for each try
read -r c && [ -n "${c##*[!0-9]*}" ]        #fails if input not number or empty
do echo "Invalid selection."; done          #prints a notice and retries
```

Last you can just `shift` away any unnecessary parameters and call `$1`:

```
shift "$((c-1))"; $1
```

It is better to verify there are no leading zeroes. `shift` will just error if the user has selected a number too high.

```
[ "$((c=$(printf %.d "$c")))" -gt 0 ] || exit 
shift "$((c-1))" && $1
```

This is for a numeric selection list, which makes the positional array very useful. More generally you might use a `case` statement:

```
case "$choice" in
(pattern 1)  do as necessary for a match;;
(pattern 2)  do otherwise for this match;;
(pattern 3)  continue this wise for each;;
(*)          until there isn't a match  ;;
esac
```

These are but portable means of emulating what many shells *(to include `bash`)* will offer as a `select` statement as introduced by `ksh` many years ago.

From `man bash`:

- `select` *name* [ `in` *word* ] ; `do` *list* ; `done`

  - The list of words following in is  expanded, generating  a  list  of  items.   The set of expanded words is printed  on  the  standard error, each preceded by a number.  If the *in word* is omitted, the  positional  parameters *(or `"$@"`)* are printed (see PARAMETERS below).  The `$PS3` prompt is then displayed  and  a  line  read from  the  standard input.